# How to pass the Like value from one component to another component using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm a newbie to react, there is a Data component where we show Quotation title, if anyone is interested then they will click on the details and they could fill the form. When we see on the beside the title, the no.of users interested number (Like ) will get displayed. When we click on the Like Link then it will redirect to the `ViewDetails` component to show the details of the user. My objective is to get the number of user interested. But couldn't able to get the number of the `Like` Link from the `ViewDetails` component. Can anyone help me in this query?

Data Component:

```
class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("/api/post")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          Data: data
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { Data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {Data.map(data => {
          return (
            <div key={data.DId}>
              <div className="a-header">{data.title}</div>
              <div className="mylink">
                <Link to={`/Fillform/${data.DId}`}>
                  Details <Icon name="angle double right" size="small" />
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="link">
                <Link to={`/ViewDetails/${data.Did}`}>Like</Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Data;
```

ViewData COmponent :

```
class ViewDetails extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      View: [],
      Like: '',

    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  fetchData() {
    fetch("/api/Users/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          View: data.item1,
          Like: data.item2
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { View } = this.state;
    return (
      <Segment>
        {View.map(tab => {
          return (
            <Table color="blue" className="myresponse">
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>Email</Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Header>

              <Table.Body key={tab.DId}>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.Cell>{tab.name}</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell>{tab.email}</Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Body>
            </Table>
          );
        })}
      </Segment>
    );
  }
}
```

Here from ViewDetails i have to get the no.of interested Users through `Like` variable.

My query is if we cant get the number from viewDetails then we need to make Parent and child COmponent.
But i couldn't able to figure it out how to make Parent and Child component for these two components.

"https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-engelbart-s8xfp"
Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From the component try passing it like this:

```
<Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/ViewDetails/${data.Did}",
      likes: {data.Did}
   }}>
    Like
</Link>
```

In receiving component , access it using

```
this.props.location.likes
```

Comment: I've written Like name in between the <link>, there i need to pass the data. These 2 components are independent components. Both of them are linked through Routing

Comment: you mean  here <div className="link">
                <Link to={`/ViewDetails/${data.Did}`}>Like</Link>
              </div>?

Comment: Yes, here i have to get the like value instead of `like word`

Comment: are you passing this value from any component? I dont see you passing this value from ViewDetails

Comment: @I'm trying to pass the Like value from `ViewData` component. I dont know how to pass it. But i tried to give the same API in `Data component`  for retrieving the `like value` but value is getting overloaded again and again like a loop

Comment: What I meant is I dont see you calling Data Component inside render of ViewDetails? Or Am I missing something here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210860/discussion-between-sanjana-and-sv12).